# In each of the following cases, prove that the given function is a homomorphism and describe its image and kernel.

Tags: group-theory

The function $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $f(x,y)=2x-y$.

What I have written:

In order to prove that $f$ is a homomorphism, we need to prove that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, for all $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$. However, the left hand side is simply $f(x+y)=2x-y$, while the right hand side is simply $f(x)+f(y)=f(x,0)+f(0,y)=2x-y$. 
Since $2x-y=2x-y$, the requirement is satisfied so $f$ is a homomorphism. 
The image of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$. 
Since the identity in $\mathbb{R}$ is $0$, the kernel of $f$ is the rest 
$\{x,y \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}|f(x,y)=0\}=\{x,y \in \mathbb{R}|2x-y=0\}$ therefore $2x=y$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this correct?

Comment: You have asked many questions on this site but have accepted no answers. More people will be willing to help you if you accept and upvote the help you get here.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm going to start doing that, still new to using this site. So if there is an answer that I find helpful, just click the up arrow each time?

Comment: Two ways to reward answers: click the check box to accept the one that helps most, click theup arrow to upvote any good answers (you may upvote the one you accept, too). Also: learn to use mathjax to format the mathematics in your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (too long for a comment):

You have to think more carefully about what's in the domain. In this case writing $f(x+y)$ makes no sense, since $f$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$. You should be thinking about
$$
f((x_1,y_1) + (x_2,y_2)) = \cdots ?
$$